# Removing or hiding event from full calender

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am trying to remove an event based on whether or not that event is less than the current date. If the particular event is less than the current date it should be removed or hidden from the full calendar.

```
   this.renderCalendar = new Calendar(document.querySelector('#calendar'),
{

eventDataTransform:(data: any)=>{
    data.start = data.start.toDate()// convert to date
    //data.end = data.end.toDate()
    const newDate = new Date().getDate();

    if(newDate>data.start.getDate()){

    //this.dataService.eventDelete(data.id);
         var event=this.renderCalendar.getEventById(data.id);
        console.log(event);
        console.log(data.id);
    //event.remove();
     }

    else{
      data.color="blue";
    }
    return data;

  },

}

);
```

I was able to come up with an implementation as above. The data is being fetched from my database. I always get a null event, eventhough I am able to get an id from the data.
What must be wrong with my code?

Comment: " I always get a null event"...where exactly? I mean, on which line of code do you find the event is null? Do you get a specific error message in the console? If so please tell us the exact error.

Comment: there is no specific error message, when I console log data.id I get an id , but when I console.log an event I get null

Answer (score 0):

During eventDataTransform, the event has not been rendered yet. eventDataTransform happens while fullCalendar is still processing each incoming event, but before they are added to the calendar. Therefore, the event does not yet exist in the calendar, so it cannot be returned from a call to `getEventById`.

I see you want to remove the event in certain circumstances. The eventDataTransform documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) says:

> The function must return a parsable Event object or false, which will
>   discard the event.

Therefore to solve your problem you can just `return false` from your eventDataTransform callback when you decide the event is not needed.

e.g.

```
  eventDataTransform: (data: any) => {
    data.start = data.start.toDate() // convert to date
    const newDate = new Date().getDate();

    if(newDate > data.start.getDate()) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      data.color="blue";
      return data;
    }
  },
```